# Create a simple json response which can be accessed from webview of an android application

Tags: php, android, json

I have a url site.com/test.php   which has the following code

```
<?php

$num1 = $_REQUEST['num1'] ;
$num2 = $_REQUEST['num2'] ;

$tot = $num1 + $num2 ;

?>
```

From an android application using POST/GET num1 and num2 parameters are passed to www.site.com/test.php

How can I make the response in such  a way that the android application will be able to get the response from this request.

I tried this

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
```

but all it does is echo it in the web view and im not able to get the response.Is there someway I can get the response as standard json response,which is not displayed but get it as soon as I hit the url as a response ?

** UPDATE **

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url) {

    if(flag) { 

            URL aURL = new URL(url); 
            URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection(); 
            conn.connect(); 
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream(); 
            // read inputstream to get the json..
            ...
            ...
            return true;
    }

    return false
}

@override
public void onPageFinished (WebView view, String url) {
    if (url contains "form.html") {
        flag = true;
    }
}
```

this is the java code I got from SO , which Im planning to use in the android appication

Comment: Show us the `JAVA` code you have that makes the request.

Comment: Actually im not doing the android part.Its done by my friend on the other side.IF I can set this api correctly he should be able to access it

Comment: Then the issue is on his end. When creating a JSON end point, you're simply trying to echo out a JSON string. Because JSON is language agnostic, it will look like `{"This": "Is a JSON string"}` in your browser, amongst other things. if it does, then it's proper.

Comment: Oh okay.So imgetting the response as {"total":13} . But the this cant be accessed from the webview

Comment: Then the issue, as I said previously, lay on the end of the Android Developer, not you.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a problem in the handling of the response, not the generation of the JSON. Are you clicking a link to the JSON on a page that is has "form.html" in it? Because that is what seems to be assumed in the code you posted.

It seems to be better to just overload the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` and check if the url matches your json page. Something like this:

```java
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url) {

    if(url.toLowerCase().contains("www.site.com/test.php")) { 
            URL aURL = new URL(url); 
            URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection(); 
            conn.connect(); 
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream(); 
            // read inputstream to get the json..
            ...
            ...
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

*It might be a good idea to start an activity and load the JSON in that activity using, for example, an AsyncTask (network operations aren't allowed on the UI thread in the latest android APIs), instead of doing URL.openConnection immediately.*